# Getting specific value from HTML attribute using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to know is it possible to get the img_url value using only CSS so i can use images as background for every tr element.

```
<tr class="title-row" id="title-49042" data-title-id="49042" data-attrs="{"global_rates":{"total":9.1099999999999994,"story":9.0299999999999994,"graphics":8.9199999999999999,"music":8.6799999999999997,"titlecahracters":9.0800000000000001},"img_url":"\/res\/images\/100x100\/208614.jpg"}">
```

I have no access to html just the CSS file. The img urls are generated automatically for every tr element.

Comment: There are no variables in CSS. You can't have dynamic styles using only CSS.

Comment: I made a few mistakes not delating ; when correcting &quot; into " it's good now

Comment: Could you fix this to valid HTML?

Comment: @Hoodboi NO you can't,

Comment: @Seblor CSS does has variables, but still in experiment stages. [For more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)

Comment: Your comment still isn't valid HTML; are some of those quotes meant to be `&quot;`? I'm guessing that `data-attrs` is meant to be escaped JSON?

Comment: @ShanilFernando Interesting. Still not fully supported in edge though, but thanks.

Comment: @JordanGray I'm sure it's exactly the same as on the website

Comment: @ShanilFernando it's interesting and works on UC Browser without any problem but I don't see it being useful in this situation

Comment: @Hoodboi The only way this could work as HTML would be: `<tr class="title-row" id="title-49042" data-title-id="49042" data-attrs="{&quot;global_rates&quot;:{&quot;total&quot;:9.1099999999999994,&quot;story&quot;:9.0299999999999994,&quot;graphics&quot;:8.9199999999999999,&quot;music&quot;:8.6799999999999997,&quot;titlecahracters&quot;:9.0800000000000001},&quot;img_url&quot;:&quot;\/res\/images\/100x100\/208614.jpg&quot;}">`. Maybe something unescaped the quotes automatically when you copied the attribute? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant to escape those quotes within `data-attr` so that it's valid HTML, this isn't possible.

Eventually, browsers will support the [new `attr` syntax](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#attr-notation) that allows specifying a `type` parameter. That will allow for things like:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: attr(data-img url);
}
```

```html
<div data-img="https://unsplash.it/200"></div>
```

**Unfortunately:**

1. As of time of writing, no browser supports this.
2. Even if they did, there's no way to extract a JSON value from an attribute using only CSS.

What you are trying to achieve is currently, and possibly always will be, impossible. The only way to do what you want is to change the HTML or use JavaScript.